# aapt.exe has stopped working after adding library to an existing project

Tags: android

I am adding one library into my existing code but while doing that the following error occurred:
"aapt.exe has stop working"

i am using eclipse indigo, Android Development Tools version 20.0.2.v201207191942-407447
i  have done all the things regarding this issue
like 1)change window>> pref>> android>> build>> to silent
     2)update necessary software
     3)clean and build projects

Comment: I can't believe I actually miss iOS development.  Someone please help us!

Answer (score 1):

try this  Remove id from style like here @+id then build again you get success...

```
<item name="android:id">@+id/calender</item>
```